# Forbes.com writer looking for up-and-running examples of data driven applications that improve human services in government

Tags: data.gov, uses-of-open-data

I am a writer for Forbes.com / Forbes Insights.

I am looking for examples of how data is being used to improve the quality in the government provision of human services provision in:

- Child Welfare
- Income Security
- Nutritional support
- Employment training/work
- Seniors/aging populations
- Housing/homelessness
- Disability

I am looking for proven (applications that are up and running in state, local or federal government locations) examples -- although beta counts!!! (So long as a real government agency is testing it!)

I am also looking for thought leaders -- gurus with credentials -- who can speak on the subject of how data can improve human services in government.

Are you a good candidate for an interview for this report?

Comment: most of those areas haven't been the most forthright in engaging in/releasing open data. would you accept apps that prove open data works?

Comment: This doesn't seem like a suitable question for Stack Exchange. Answers are likely to be mere lists, and would become obsolete sooner than later.

Answer (score 3):

Some colleagues and I started cataloging some different interesting ways government data is being used:

https://github.com/18F/ideas/issues/2

I'm no expert on this, and this doesn't *quite* answer your question, but hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There is a recent blog post from the [Sunlight Foundation](http://sunlightfoundation.com) that seems to answer your question:

**[A new approach to measuring the impact of open data](http://sunlightfoundation.com/blog/2015/05/05/a-new-approach-to-measuring-the-impact-of-open-data/)**

- A [searchable repository](https://docs.google.com/a/sunlightfoundation.com/spreadsheets/d/1jP6WIkEPczb8MBn6DNOU2PhKp9Prwe4HokqhUQVsxE0/edit) of more than 100 examples on the outputs, outcomes and impacts of open data and digital technology projects

> The case stories we collected aim to illustrate the social impact of open data and digital transparency initiatives in different countries, cities and communities. We gathered examples on how users are empowered by open government initiatives as well as how open data and digital transparency projects are changing the behavior, relationships, activities and actions of users. Instead of basic project descriptions and mere output, we wanted to seek evidence on how open data and technology help to influence governance and improve lives, both directly and indirectly. After reviewing the examples, our research team compiled the data to form a database with basic facts, short descriptions and links, then categorizing the repository into a couple of significant fields/sectors.

- Full paper on Scribd: [The Social Impact of Open Data](http://www.scribd.com/doc/263776138/The-Social-Impact-of-Open-Data)

([my source](https://twitter.com/SunFoundation/status/600063496856817664))